# Android Studio: Popup window layout with buttons onClick

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hello I am trying to make a pop up window with 4 buttons that change the map type on a Google Maps activity. I have set the on click listener in the class with the GoogleMap object, but I get this error when clicking one of the buttons.

```
 Process: com.student.nick.earthquakereport, PID: 7770
          java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method setMapNormal(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.widget.Button with id 'mapNormal'
                    at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(View.java:4485)
                    at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4449)
                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21156)
                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

The dialog is launched in the same class the onClick methods are in.

```
layFlator = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ViewGroup containter = (ViewGroup) layFlator.inflate(R.layout.map_settings, null);

    mapSettings = new PopupWindow(containter, 750, 680, true);
    mapSettings.setAnimationStyle(R.style.PopupAnimation);
    mapSettings.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0,0);

    containter.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            mapSettings.dismiss();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

The methods

```
public void setMapNormal(View view) {
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    mapSettings.dismiss();
}

public void setMapHybrid(View view) {
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    mapSettings.dismiss();
}

public void setMapTerrain(View view) {
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
    mapSettings.dismiss();
}

public void setMapSat(View view) {
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
    mapSettings.dismiss();
}
```

Thanks for taking a look

EDIT: The layout the popup opens

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fadingEdge="horizontal|vertical"
android:fadingEdgeLength="4dp"
android:elevation="20dp"
android:background="@drawable/popwindow_border"
>


<Button
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Normal"
    android:id="@+id/mapNormal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:onClick="setMapNormal"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hybrid"
    android:id="@+id/mapHybrid"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:onClick="setMapHybrid"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Terrain"
    android:id="@+id/mapTerrain"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:onClick="setMapTerrain"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Satellite"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:onClick="setMapSat"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I looked around and found a tutorial, this is the proper way to do it.

```
layFlator = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View popUp =  layFlator.inflate(R.layout.map_settings, null);

    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popUp, 750, 680, true);
    popupWindow.setAnimationStyle(R.style.PopupAnimation);

    Button btnHybrid = (Button) popUp.findViewById(R.id.mapHybrid);
    btnHybrid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            Log.d("hybrid", "called");
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Instead of putting SOLVED in the title, you can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your error msg clearly says:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method
>   setMapNormal(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick
>   attribute defined on view class android.widget.Button with id
>   'mapNormal'

So, you are not accessing the method right in the onClickListener. You can't just call the method using

```
this.methodName()
```

inside a handler. You might want to use something like

```
ClassName.this.methodName()
```

or

```
getActivity().methodName()
```

Comment: My on click listener is set in the XML, so I cannot do it that way I guess
      <Button
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Normal"
        android:id="@+id/mapNormal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="setMapNormal"/>

Comment: The popup is an activity.xml, can i attach a class to it and just pass extras?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can add an onClickListener that way. At least I've never happened to do it. Try removing it from there and putting it in your Java code and check of or works.

Comment: First you need to initialize your button. It is null when you are seeing the onClickListener. Use findViewById to get the button first

Comment: with the code showed in [pastebin.com/3LdE6wp2](http://pastebin.com/3LdE6wp2), it seems the ''mapHybrid Button'' is in the xml which you use for the contentView of popupwindow, no the Activity.
Before you use `findViewbyId` method in a activity, you should call `setContentView(View view)` method, otherwise `findViewbyId` will return null.
Like this:
`setContentView(R.layout.xxx);
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yyy)`
the button yyy is in xxx.xml

Comment: If I do that then the view will cover up my activity.

Answer (score 0):

You are not set onClickListener correctly. Take a look at [android:onClick](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#onClick).

> For instance, if you specify android:onClick="sayHello", you must declare a public void sayHello(View v) method of your context (typically, your Activity).

Comment: I have done that, its in the activity's java class the popup window is over